# Not able to store value on mapping

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Lending {
    // calculating the value of loan on the basis of collateral
    uint256 LTV = 20;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmt;
    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToTime;

    function modifyLTV(uint256 _newVal) public {
        LTV = _newVal;
    }

    // 0.00002(RBTC)*10^8=2000RSAT
    function calculateLoanAmt(uint256 _collateralVal)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 num = _collateralVal * 20;
        uint256 denom = 100;
        return num / denom; // It is returning the value in RSAT
    }

    function requestForLoan(uint256 _collateralVal) internal returns (uint256) {
        uint256 eligibleAmt = calculateLoanAmt(_collateralVal);
        addressToAmt[msg.sender] = eligibleAmt;
        addressToTime[msg.sender] = block.number;

        return eligibleAmt;
    }
}
```

in the addressToAmt mapping the eligibleAmt value should be added , but everytime I'm querying data in addressToAmt it is returning 0.

Remix output:

"0": "uint256: 0"

Although the return value of  requestForLoan() is as expected. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: your question is not much clear. add some examples or scenarios

Comment: How are you checking it on Remix?, you should input the msg.sender address

Answer (score 0):

I've modified the viewing of `requestForLoan` to public and it worked for me.

```js
function requestForLoan(uint256 _collateralVal) public returns (uint256) {
        uint256 eligibleAmt = calculateLoanAmt(_collateralVal);
        addressToAmt[msg.sender] = eligibleAmt;
        addressToTime[msg.sender] = block.number;

        return eligibleAmt;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code you published is not the same as the Remix example. `requestForLoan` is marked `internal` when it clearly has to be `external` or `public`.

With that one change, 150 => 30. I get a non-zero `addressToTime` as well, so I'm not sure what we're trying to solve here.

[image]